# Truncate and show or hide the link text when clicking on "read more" link

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to hide the text if limit exceed to 300 chars and show the `link` and if click on link then show the full content.

html:

```
 <tr v-for="(row,index) in datasource">
                            <td v-for="column in gridSchema.grid.columns" class="wrap-break-word" v-show="column.isVisible">  

<span v-if="row[column.headername].length >= 300  && toggle == false" v-html="$options.filters.limitTo(row[column.headername])">
                                    </span><a v-on:click="toggleFlag()" v-show="!row['isEditable'] && row[column.headername].length >= 300  && toggle == false" >Read more</a>
                                    <span v-if="(row[column.headername].length < 300  || toggle == true)" v-html="row[column.headername]">
                                    </span>

<td>
</tr>
```

js:

```
  data: {
                ..
                    toggle: false,
datasource:
[
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Christa Hansen",
        "informations": "Unpleasant astonished an diminution up partiality. Noisy an their of meant. Death means up civil do an offer wound of. Called square an in afraid direct. Resolution diminution conviction so mr at unpleasing simplicity no. No it as breakfast up conveying earnestly immediate principle. Him son disposed produced humoured overcame she bachelor improved. Studied however out wishing but inhabit fortune windows. "
        "biliography":"Remember outweigh do he desirous no cheerful. Do of doors water ye guest. We if prosperous comparison middletons at. Park we in lose like at no."
     },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mckenzie Fuller",
        "informations":"Did shy say mention enabled through elderly improve."
        "biliography":" It ye greatest removing concerns an overcame appetite. Manner result square father boy behind its his. Their above spoke match ye mr right oh as first. Be my depending to believing perfectly concealed household. Point could to built no hours smile sense. "
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Oneal Clark",
        "informations": "-",
        "biliography":"-"

      }
    ]
               ..
            }
    methods:{

    toggleFlag: function () {
                    console.log('within toggleflag final');
                    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
                }

    },
     filters: {
                limitTo: function (value) {
                    if (!value) return '';
                    return value.substring(0, 300 )+ '...';
                }
```

---

edit : above code works but when click on "Read More" then it applied to all the columns of table wherever it shows the link.

example: Table Row's col1 , col5 are exceed the 300 chars and shows the "read more" link. when click on col1's "read more" link then it also applies to col5 and both the column's text are expanded for all the rows.
It should apply to particular row and particular cell.

added datasource object. I added static datasource but it is dynamic and varies for number of columns.

Comment: please provide your data object and template

Comment: Updated how I call. need to flip show/hide content if exceed the limit text.

Comment: check my answer using the computed property

Comment: you need to be more explicit about what you want, you have two answers that have two different interpretations of what you want

Comment: It would be helpful to see example input and desired output.

Comment: added details @Slotheroo

Comment: could you provide your `datasource` property structure?

Comment: added datasource structure. (it is dynamic but that contains large columns how added above).

Comment: @user3711357 i update my answer, i hope that it would help you

Answer (score 6):

Using **v-if**
 `v-if="obj.informations.length > 300"`

**Example:**

```
<div v-if="summary">
  {{ obj.informations | linitToDisplay(300) }}
  <a v-if="obj.informations.length > 300" @click="summary = false">Read more<a>
<div v-else>
  {{ obj.informations }}
</div>
```

But you'd probably write toggleSummary() method instead of the inline `summary = false` handler and maybe use computed property that reacts to summary instead of a filter.

Comment: thanks for the message, I applied this solution on tabular grid format but it applies to all the records instead of particular cell value. (Added details on edited question).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `computed` property to handle that case and when you click on the link the whole link text will be shown :

**EDIT**

i suggest the following solution which built by altering your `datasource` and by modifying each cell in the `mounted` hook, `"id":0` will be `"id":{txt:0,toggled:true}`, `"informations":"..."` will be `"informations":{txt:"...",toggled:false}` and so on. and when you click on a cell you will only modify its `toggled` property to `false`

```js
// ignore the following two lines, they just disable warnings in "Run code snippet"
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      toggle: false,
      link: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum augue eros, varius in massa vitae, ultrices fringilla eros',
      showAll: false,
      columns: ["id", "name", "informations", "biliography"],
      datasource: [{
          "id": 0,
          "name": "Christa Hansen",
          "informations": "Unpleasant astonished an diminution up partiality. Noisy an their of meant. Death means up civil do an offer wound of. Called square an in afraid direct. Resolution diminution conviction so mr at unpleasing simplicity no. No it as breakfast up conveying earnestly immediate principle. Him son disposed produced humoured overcame she bachelor improved. Studied however out wishing but inhabit fortune windows. ",
          "biliography": "Remember outweigh do he desirous no cheerful. Do of doors water ye guest. We if prosperous comparison middletons at. Park we in lose like at no."
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Mckenzie Fuller",
          "informations": "Did shy say mention enabled through elderly improve.",
          "biliography": " It ye greatest removing concerns an overcame appetite. Manner result square father boy behind its his. Their above spoke match ye mr right oh as first. Be my depending to believing perfectly concealed household. Point could to built no hours smile sense. "
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Oneal Clark",
          "informations": "some info",
          "biliography": "some info"

        }
      ]

    }
  },
  computed: {
    trunc_link() {
      return this.link.substring(0, 30)
    }
  },
  methods: {

    toggleFlag: function(index, column) {
      this.datasource[index][column].toggled = true;
    },
    limitTo: function(value) {
      if (!value) return '';
      return value.substring(0, 50) + '...';
    }

  },
  mounted() {
    let d = [];
    d = this.datasource.map(item => {
      let o = {
        "id": {
          txt: item.id,
          toggled: true
        },
        "name": {
          txt: item.name,
          toggled: true
        },
        "informations": {
          txt: item.informations,
          toggled: false
        },
        "biliography": {
          txt: item.biliography,
          toggled: false
        },

      }
      return o;
    });

    this.datasource = d;
    //console.log(this.datasource)
  }
});
```

```css
.readmore {
  color: #005faa!important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">

  <a href="#" v-if="!showAll" @click="showAll=true"> {{trunc_link}}...</a>
  <a href="#" v-else> {{link}}</a>
  <table class="table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row,index) in datasource">
        <td v-for="column in columns" class="wrap-break-word" v-show="true">

          <span v-if="row[column].txt.length >= 50  && row[column].toggled == false" v-html="limitTo(row[column].txt)">
                                    </span><a class="readmore" v-on:click="toggleFlag(index,column)" v-show="!row['isEditable'] && row[column].txt.length >= 50  && row[column].toggled == false">Read more</a>
          <span v-if="(row[column].txt.length < 50  || row[column].toggled == true)" v-html="row[column].txt">
                                    </span>

          <td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```