# (Vue.js) Class binding doesn't work with variants that refer to another data property

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm making a simple TODO app. In my index.html I have a root div with an id `#app`. There I have a div with prior class `.todobox`. In this div I shall list variants, which I keep in my main.js. Each variant has a special property called `varStyle`, that should edit each `.todobox` accordingly. I do this, because I need my done tasks to be displayed with grey background and undone - with a red one.

**Problem:** no matter what type of `varStyle` I put, they all display with the same style of the main `.todobox`. Oddly enough the console doesn't show any major issues.

What can be done to fix this issue? I will appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

```js
var todo = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        styleundone: {
            backgroundColor: 'crimson',
        },
        styledone: {
            textDecoration: 'line-through',
            backgroundColor: 'gray'
        },
        variants: [
            {
                varID: 2333,
                varDesc: 'Create a new instance',
                varStyle: this.styledone
            },
            {
                varID: 2345,
                varDesc: 'Boot up the computer',
                varStyle: this.styledone
            },
            {
                varID: 2787,
                varDesc: 'Open Google Chrome',
                varStyle: this.styledone
            }
        ],
    }
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0
}

#app {
    margin: 2%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.header {
    height: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(162,148,203,0.7651435574229692) 0%, rgba(228,147,205,1) 50%, rgba(169,163,214,0.7035189075630253) 100%);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.todobox {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px black solid;
    border-radius: 5%;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 14px 10px 5px -1px rgba(255,153,255,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 14px 10px 5px -1px rgba(255,153,255,1);
    box-shadow: 14px 10px 5px -1px rgba(255,153,255,1);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.todobox:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.todobox:active {
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: all 0.3s
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=devide-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>ToDo List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Todo List</h1>
        </div>
    
        <div id="app">
            
                <div class="todobox" 
                v-for="variant in variants"
                :key="variant.varID"
                :style="variant.varStyle">
                <p>{{ variant.varDesc }}</p>
                </div>

        </div>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `variants` as a computed property in order to get access to the data property `styledone` because you cannot refer to data property inside another one  :

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;


var todo = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    styleundone: {
      backgroundColor: 'crimson',
    },
    styledone: {
      textDecoration: 'line-through',
      backgroundColor: 'gray'
    },

  },
  computed: {
    variants() {

      return [{
          varID: 2333,
          varDesc: 'Create a new instance',
          varStyle: this.styledone
        },
        {
          varID: 2345,
          varDesc: 'Boot up the computer',
          varStyle: this.styledone
        },
        {
          varID: 2787,
          varDesc: 'Open Google Chrome',
          varStyle: this.styledone
        }
      ]

    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

#app {
  margin: 2%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(162, 148, 203, 0.7651435574229692) 0%, rgba(228, 147, 205, 1) 50%, rgba(169, 163, 214, 0.7035189075630253) 100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.todobox {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px black solid;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 14px 10px 5px -1px rgba(255, 153, 255, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 14px 10px 5px -1px rgba(255, 153, 255, 1);
  box-shadow: 14px 10px 5px -1px rgba(255, 153, 255, 1);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.todobox:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.todobox:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  transition: all 0.3s
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=devide-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>ToDo List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Todo List</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="app">

    <div class="todobox" v-for="variant in variants" :key="variant.varID" :style="variant.varStyle">
      <p>{{ variant.varDesc }}</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It worked! By the way, why did you add ```Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;``` in main.js?

Comment: to ignore the message that says `Download the Vue Devtools extension for a better development experience:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools ...`  but here doesn't work :) , but it worked in this my old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52728718/8172857)