# How do I display one object of an array in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, vuejs2

Let's say I have this list of objects in Vue.JS

```
data () {
return{
  examples: [
    {
      exampleID: 5,
      exampleText: 'foo'
    },
    {
      exampleID: 3,
      exampleText: 'bar'
    }
  ]
}
}
```

Now let's say I want to display the object with the exampleID of 3 in an element i created before

```
   <Task 
  v-for="example in examples"
  :key="example.exampleID"
  :example="example"
/>
```

I want to display everything, that is in the object (the ID and the text)

Task component :

```
<template>
    <div class="exercise">
        <div class="exercise-id">
            <h1>ID NUMBER: {{ example.exampleID }}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="exercise-task">
            <h2>{{ example.exampleText}}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
 
<script>
 
export default {
  name: 'Task',
  props: ['example']
}
</script>
```

Comment: your question is not clear enough, please share the Task component code

Comment: The Task component is in an external file in the components folder. Here's the code https://pastebin.com/T1czudfh

Comment: the Task component has different prop

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to rename that I will do that in a second, but I just want to know how I can display One object of an array I've tried doing v-if="example.exampleID== 3" but it didn't work

Comment: the properties shown in the task component are different from that defined in parent component except `ExampleID`

Comment: should be correct now.

Comment: So now what do you actually expect here?

Comment: I just want to know how I can display the content of ONE object of the given array. For example I want to display one Task element with content of the object with the exampleID of 3.

Comment: Try adding this below v-for statement....................

v-show="example.exampleID === 3"

Comment: It works! Thank you very much, I totally forgot about this directive.

Comment: @DavidD. it a bad practice to loop through array to only show one object, try to use a computed property as i suggested below because it will be cached and more performant

Comment: @DavidD if the below answers are working fine please do upvote it so that it would be encouraging. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `v-if` and `v-for` in the same element, in this case i suggest to use a computed property that only return the desired example :

```
data () {
return{
  examples: [
    {
      exampleID: 5,
      exampleText: 'foo'
    },
    {
      exampleID: 3,
      exampleText: 'bar'
    }
  ]
}
},
computed:{
    myExample(){
       return this.examples.find(ex=>ex.exampleID===3)
    }
}
```

then render it like :

```
  <Task   :example="myExample"/>
```

Comment: Thank you this one works just as fine as the v-show directive, but I am still gonna stick to your solution if you say it's more performant!

Answer (score 2):

Another efficient way of doing it without v-for is

```
data () {
return{
  examples: [
    {
      exampleID: 5,
      exampleText: 'foo'
    },
    {
      exampleID: 3,
      exampleText: 'bar'
    }
  ],
  id: 3
}
},
computed:{
    myExample(){
       return id => this.examples.find(ex=>ex.exampleID===id)
    }
}
```

rendering part will be like

```
<Task :example="myExample(id)"/>
```

In this way you no need to hardcode the value as 3 in the computed property.

Comment: computed is a property not a method, it doesn't accept parameters, try to ,call it id with `this` something like `return this.examples.find(ex=>ex.exampleID===this.id)` and `<Task :example="myExample"/>`

Comment: could you provide running example? you could use the running example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52728718/8172857)